# How to tell if ALTER PROCEDURE worked?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and SQL Server. I'm trying to run an `ALTER PROCEDURE` query from a `.sql` file called through C# code. Before I move on to making sure my query does what it's supposed to do, I want to verify that my `ALTER PROCEDURE` query actually altered the procedure, but I don't know how to verify that.

For example, in SQL Server, I can see where the stored procedure I'm trying to edit lives, in:

```
 - database-name
     - Programmability/
         - Stored Procedures/
          - dbo.MyStoredProcedure
```

If my `ALTER TABLE` query worked correctly, would I be able to see my procedure code here, or would I check somewhere else? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

---

Comment: If it doesn't work that means it raised an exception which you would be able to capture inside your catch block in your c# code. That of course is assuming you are executing the code block(s) against your database.

Comment: Show your app code. Much depends on how you execute that SQL file.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are 2 different phases when altering an SP, one is the actual alter command which will **parse** the new SP code and another phase is the **compilation** which will be done when the SP is executed for the first time after it was altered. And yes, if the alter was successful, you should see the updated code if you open the SP code through SSMS on the route you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, we rely on error and exception messages to tell us when something like this has not worked.  However, I suppose that it might be possible that the procedure Alter-ed was not the one that was intended (implying bugs in the name/path/call construction, of course).

In that case, you can get the current text of any SQL Module (Procedure, View, Trigger, etc., anything script-baseD) from the `sys.sql_modules` table:

```
SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.UserSamples_Insert')
```

You should note that usually when something like this happens without an error message it is because either:

1. You are executing in the wrong database (like PROD when you meant to be in DEV or vice-versa), or
2. You are not using the correct Schema (because you can make and use schemas other than `'dbo'`).

---

Wait, you say `ALTER PROCEDURE` twice, but then the third time you say `ALTER TABLE`.  Which is it?  I ask because unlike almost every other SQL object, tables are *not* script-based and their definition cannot be found in any of the Sql script repositories like sys.sql_modules. I actually use either SMO (from a client) or a tool that @SeanLange wrote years ago for that (from the server itself).